# Unable to remove product image

Tags: product, product-attribute

I can not seem to remove a specific product image in Magento. When I select the remove checkbox and click save and continue, the image is still there. Also no error message is shown.

I thought it might have to do with permissions, but I checked and in the media folder these are all 0777.

I have also seen that there are differences between the number of images in each storefront. The German store has 5, which does not include inane number 6 which I want to remove. The Dutch store has six, which does contain image nr six which I want to remove.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Patrick Steenks,

As you have multiple store and each store have different different images....

So,you  need to

select one `particular Product chang`e store at product label
`selecting remove checkbox` and `click save and continue that is removing  all image of product of that particular store` and same way need  `to follow  remove other stores products image that particular product.`

**Import note:** `remove checkbox` only `remove  image path from db`. it do `not  remove image from folder`.

If you want remo`ve all image of products from db and folder then write a  script` 
 `include admin as store` and `programmatically fetch all image` and using unlink function remove the images from folder and  `write script remove images from db`

Comment: Yes, that is what I tried. However, the images was still there, even after removing it at each storefront. I do see that the filename was quite long (147 characters), maybe that is related. I solved it by removing it from the database.

Comment: then you need write a script which remove all image of product..I will provide shortly.

Comment: No problem it is working now. I also have to remove the check with the boxes to use the standard values for each storeview.

Comment: Sorry, I already upvoted, but did not accept. Done now. :)

Comment: i have already put up vote for answer